# Subseries with indexes powers of 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n\geq 0$ be a non-increasing sequence, $\alpha , q >0 $, and assume:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k^\alpha a_k)^q}{k} \leq 1 $$
Then 
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty (2^{j\alpha} a_{2^j})^q \leq c_{\alpha,q}$$

Where $c_{\alpha,q}$ depends only on $\alpha$ and $q$.

If the last expression was divided by $2^j$, then this would be obvious, but how do I "get rid" of the denominator? I'm thinking Cauchy-Schwarz but didn't get very far with it. I don't know how Cauchy-Schwarz can produce a bound dependent on $\alpha$ and $q$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that 
$$\tag{(1)}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}k^{\alpha q-1}\alpha_k^q=\sum_{l=0}^{+\infty}
\sum_{k=2^l}^{2^{l+1}-1}k^{\alpha q-1}\alpha_k^q$$
Since $(a_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ is non-increasing, 
$$\sum_{k=2^l}^{2^{l+1}-1}k^{\alpha q-1}\alpha_k^q\geqslant 2^l2^{l(\alpha q-1)}a_{2^{l+1}-1}\geqslant 2^{l\alpha q}a_{2^{l+1}},$$
we obtain by (1) and the assumption,
$$\sum_{l=0}^{+\infty}2^{l\alpha q}a_{2^{l+1}}=2^{\alpha q}\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}2^{j\alpha q}a_{2^j}\leqslant 1,$$
and the conclusion follows.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it now. But shouldn't that first inequality be opposite? Also, I think we need to consider $\alpha q \geq 1$ and $\alpha q < 1$ separately.

Comment: You are right (otherwise the bound $k^{aq-1}\geqslant 2^{l(aq-1)}$ wouldn't be valid). If $aq-1>0$, then the first inequality holds.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and this works (for $\alpha q \leq 1$ the proof is very similar). However I still believe the index you wrote in the second term in the second line should be $a_{2^l}$ and not $a_{2^{l+1}-1}$.